# Unable to update an object inside MongoDB collection using HTTP Put?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to AngularJS and I was trying to update my MongoDB Database. I am having an issue when I am trying to update an object inside my collection. The following is my attempt at trying to do so:

```
//listviewFactory is already injected and returns an event object
//I call $scope.put when clicking (ng-click) on a button

$scope.event = listviewFactory.getEvent();

$scope.put = function(event){
    var currentUser = {};
    if($cookieStore.get('token')) {
        currentUser = User.get();
    }

    event.attendees.push(currentUser);

    $http.post('/api/events/' + event._id, event).success(function(data){
      for(var i = 0; i < event.attendees.length; i++){
        console.log("Attendees: ", event.attendees[i]);
      }

      $location.path('/');
    });

};
```

I'm just unsure of why my code isn't working. When I do the `$http put` request, my function is successful and proceeds to perform the `console.log`. When I print out the `attendees` array, I saw that the `currentUser` object is indeed appended to my `event.attendees` array. However, when I check my database using the Mongo shell, My attendees array is not updated and remains blank. Any ideas on why or where I may be wrong at? Below is also my server side code in how I am routing my application and specifying how to store the information in MongoDB.

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use('/api/events', require('./api/event'));
  ...
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
    var express = require('express');
    var controller = require('./event.controller');

    var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);

// Updates an existing event in the DB.
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Event.findById(req.params.id, function (err, event) {
    if (err) { return handleError(err); }
    if(!event) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.merge(event, req.body);
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(err); }
      return res.json(200, event);
    });
  });
};
```

EDIT: When I console.log currentUser:

```
Current User:  
Resource {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
__v: 0
_id: "53dd72fb5a24aa781a3cbde8"
email: "test@test.com"
name: "Test User"
provider: "local"
role: "user"
```

EDIT: Mongoose schema:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var EventSchema = new Schema({
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
    eventLocation: String,
    eventName: String,
    attendees: Array
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `mongoose`. Try

```
updated.markModified('attendees');
```

before
    `updated.save` call.

Regarding pushing the currentUser, do something equivalent to

```
event.attendees.push({__v: 0
    _id: "53dd72fb5a24aa781a3cbde8"
    email: "test@test.com"
    name: "Test User"
    provider: "local"
    role: "user"})
```

i.e just push the relevant fields.

Comment: Hm, so when I added in the markModified function call, I looked at my array and saw that attendees has a new object within it but it doesn't display anything (the object inside the array is blank). Any ideas why? I also added in my mongoose schema.

Comment: seems to be Schema issue. can you give us a console.log of `currentuser` and your `attendees` schema

Comment: Okay I added in the `mongoose schema` and the console.log of `currentUser`. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1871869 I am not familiar with angular very much but why are you pushing a resource into the event.attendees. Just push the object which contains the last 6 fields in the console.log you have given.

Comment: Hm, how would you do? I am pushing an object that contains the last 6 fields in the console.log I have been given. If I don't push it to even.attendees, where would you suggest I push it to?

Comment: This is not a help desk. You should debug on your own.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean it that way. Do you mind clarifying what you meant in your above comment? Or is Array the wrong type of schema to have in this database? I'm just new to using mongoose and I'm not really sure where my error is...

Comment: @user1871869 check my edit. Using Array type is fine in your schema.

Comment: Ah, okay. I will try to work with what you have given me. Thank you so much for your time and effort.